# Safari with multiple delay transition property

Tags: safari, webkit, delay, transition

I have this issue only on safari, in fact it doesn't execute the first delay I assign in this code:

```
-webkit-transition-duration:800ms,800ms;
-webkit-transition-delay:800ms, 0ms;
-webkit-transition-property::margin-left,transform;
-webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out,ease-in-out;
```

The delay of 800ms isn't working, can someone help?
NOTE: in every browser the code works (for another piece of css with all the vendor prefixes, even the one without)